# Does UWP support WRL

Tags: uwp, wrl

I have an old Media Extension sample code base on WRL, it works very well on windows 8.1. But when port it to UWP, it report error while merge metadata.

Does UWP support WRL now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

winmd position is changed, add this line in MIDL

-metadata_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata"

Answer (score 0):

The status of Windows Runtime C++ template Library (WRL) is the same as it as for Windows 8.1: It's there, it works, and you can use it but there's little to no documentation or samples on using WRL rather than C++/CX other than the use of `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` which is ubiquitous.

I use WRL in aspects of [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs and it works just fine for UWP.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx)